# list index out of range when extracting unique keywords

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract only unique words in a list from a given observation.
Here clean_doc is a list that contains data copied from a dataframe column having each row as a list of words

```
clean_doc1 = []
for i in range(len(clean_doc)):
    uniquewords = []
    k = 0
    for j in range(len(clean_doc[i])):
        if (clean_doc[i][j] == uniquewords[k]):
            pass
        else:
            uniquewords[k].append(clean_doc[i][j]) 
            k = k + 1  
    clean_doc1.append(uniquewords)
```

While performing this I am getting 'list index out of range' error.

Appreciate any help on this

Comment: Hint: does `uniquewords[k]` exist for `k=0` and `uniquewords = []`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overcomplicated. All you need is this:

```
clean_doc1 = list(map(set,clean_doc))
```